# Get Ask Ubuntu Wallpaper for Your Desktop Here!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

### What's up?

We all love Ask Ubuntu and I began thinking that it would be a great idea if we could have some wallpapers that we can use.

So please post your Ask Ubuntu-themed wallpapers below as an answer. Please also include a small preview of the wallpaper.

### How can I use them?

Basically you can use them as a background or anything else **for your own personal use**.

Comment: Cool.  What I'd love to see is a wallpaper with the (or an) Ubuntu cupcake with the something like, "Ask and You Shall Receive".  (And the askubuntu logo in there somewhere.)

Answer (score 17):

[[image]

1280x800](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/wallpaper/askubuntu.jpg)

**Note:** I currently only have one resolution: `1280x800` since that's what I have my primary monitor set to. I'm sure it would be easy to modify the image to other smaller resolutions.

**Second note:** for attribution purposes, I should mention that this image uses a modified version of the stock Ubuntu wallpaper on Natty.

Comment: Nice, love it...!

Comment: This is sexy. I demand larger, 1920x1080

Comment: I'm afraid I no longer have the original artwork for this :(

Answer (score 6):

My wallpaper is an alteration of Aubergine Sea by Wyatt Kirby

[[image]

2000x1250](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRTKC.jpg)

It can be easily resized.

Comment: +1 - Nice work.

Answer (score 6):

[[image]

1920x1200](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/wallpaper/stripes.jpg)

**Note:** for attribution purposes, I should mention that this image uses a modified version of the stock Ubuntu wallpaper (for Gnome 3) on Oneiric.

Answer (score 5):

[[image]

1280x800](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/wallpaper/sunrise.png)

**Note:** Again, I currently only have one resolution: `1280x800` since that's what I have my primary monitor set to. I'm sure it would be easy to modify the image to other smaller resolutions.

**Second note:** as the sole designer of this wallpaper, I hereby release it into the public domain.

Comment: (Note: this wallpaper looks especially nice on KDE.)

Answer (score 5):

[[image: Raring Wallpaper]

2560x1600](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pruQi.jpg)

I have taken the stock wallpaper for Raring and overlaid the Ask Ubuntu logo (with some lens flare effects and patterns).

**For attribution purposes:** this image uses a modified version of the default Ubuntu wallpaper on Raring (13.04). It is released (by me) under an identical license.

Answer (score 5):

Somebody mentioned cupcakes and I was bored.

[[image]

  1920x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Polrs.jpg)

Now am hungry and bored!

The image of cupcakes was found at imgur after googling ubuntu cupcakes.The image used can be found https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECpft.jpg which after using gimp to add "All you have to do is Ask @ ask ubuntu logo" then resizing and export as png.

Comment: Did you bake those yourself? :D