# What should we do to celebrate 100k questions?

Tags: discussion

The day is coming close! ~16 days from now at our current rate.

- http://stackexchange.com/sites#questions

Please post ideas on how we should party.

Comment: [**WE HAVE CROSSED 100K QUESTIONS**](http://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=newest)

Comment: Didn't find (yet, but it's there) question #100k...

Answer (score 14):

Some ideas...

- Live session (Hangout style) about Askubuntu, how it came to be and what does it mean to the Ubuntu community.
- Shirts! Ubuntu/Askubuntu shirts!!
- Video showing with awesome graphics the Askubuntu site, some of the most active users in the site (And also robots like Jorge) and promoting the site (And even the 13.04 version which most likely be on the same day as the release).
- Information about the site. For example, did you know askubuntu has more questions, users and visits than Unix & Linux.This has to count for something when trying to get a hold of the popularity around Ubuntu. It is also the 4th in amount of visits, users and questions per day. 5th in amount of questions. Something similar to the one that was done to github where it showed all popular git projects, amount of clones, developers, etc..

Comment: G+ hangout might be fun.

Comment: *Limited edition* shirts :)

Comment: Platinum badges for the **M**ost **V**aluable **U**sers and wooden badges for the funniest-publicly selected/voted and awarded

Comment: @geezanansa That normally only applies to moderators and people with really-high reputation. I think EVERYONE should be able to party.

Comment: An AskUbuntu shirt is a *great* idea.

Comment: @smartboyhw What? platinum badges exist all ready?.  Haven't got my wooden spoon badge yet either- "publicly selected/voted" could allow everyone to have fun. You just got your first vote for wooden spoon badge for example. :p

Answer (score 10):

Just for one day...

- give 10 bounties of 500 points for the best and most revealing SQL searches on this website
- get a special design for that day
- show a list of the 10 most popular tags and the most popular questions with that tag
- give the 100.000 question a special badge
- double the points you get for every vote and accept that day (triple them for old questions)
- make infographics showing how AU grew
- display a thank you message on the profiles
- provide a nice (and clickable?) desktop background

We could also act silly...

- give random winners fake mod power (rollback their changes afterwards)
- allow questions on RedHat for one day
- provide free beer
- spam other stackexchange websites as well as ubuntu forums claiming AU is the best
- tell our employers that this really is a holiday
- change our profile picture to a picture of us as a baby/kid
- ask random questions about Commodore 64 
  ...

Comment: Sorry did not read the whole answer. Somehow my eyes landed on Free Beer and playing on the Commodore 64.

Comment: Some of this would be impossible.. Like doubling points for votes. That's hard coded into the whole SE system. I'm not sure how much of the design we can change either.

Comment: [We already have wallpaper.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1633/get-ask-ubuntu-wallpaper-for-your-desktop-here)

Answer (score 3):

- Just a thought. How about have a question on meta about what the 100,000th question will be? A similar thing was done for the [1,000,000th Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Millionth_topic_pool) entry. Also, you could have a pool on when the 100,000th threshold will be reached, like [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Million_pool) did...
- New Idea: **Remember to update [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Askubuntu)**. It says as of September 2012, we have 70k questions. It should be updated to reflect 100k milestone. Also maybe create a new section for milestones, or a expand the history section.
- Vote for the top 10 most memorable questions, like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193901/wheres-ubuntu-desktop-12-04-1-dvd-version)!
- Someone make a VH1 remember the xx's spoof for AskUbuntu.

Comment: Oh. thank you. I totally forgot about the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Is that question really memorable?

Comment: ...made me laugh...how about [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/169918/new-whats-this)?

Comment: Ah, I wish the "I need help with this" qusetion was still around, http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5105514#5105514

Answer (score 1):

delete all questions and start from zero, than we can celebrate again when we gain that number. simple as that :D

OK just a joke :D

Answer (score -3):

Wait until we have 100k answered questions.

Answer (score -8):

Fold AskUbuntu into [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/?as=1) and maintain [unix.stackexhange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/?as=1) as the primary or only Stackexchange Unix/Linux/GNU site.

Ubuntu is not an island standing independent of the greater Linux/GNU/Unix community but is very much a part of that community. Keeping AskUbuntu as it's own island is misguided and ultimately counterproductive. Ubuntu users including newbies are ultimately enriched by exposure to that greater community.

[Stackoverlow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) which was the original, and still is the flagship, Stackexchange site provides a prime example of a vibrant diverse community that has not splintered into a multitude of Java, C# and Hadoop sub-fora. It is a vibrant community where C, C++, and Java proponents interact and contribute to everyone's benefit.

Comment: Destroy askubuntu in 100k question celebration :o. Are you serious ?

Comment: um...+1 for originality?

Comment: First of all, unix is/was an Operating System and linux is just a kernel. Secondly, Ubuntu is not just Linux, it contains far more stuff than just a kernel. Just because some part of Ubuntu (the kernel - linux) is based on unix doesn't mean they are completely same.

Comment: @haziz Unix was written in C, but that doesn't mean we should merge programming and Unix into one. The components of Ubuntu and Ubuntu itself are two different things and should remain where they are.

Comment: ...and I took my joke vote back....

Comment: Ubuntu is not just another Gnu/linux distro, It is something special. Just check number of questions and type of answers unix tack exchange which allows all distros including ubuntu and askubuntu which allows ubuntu only :)

Comment: @Tachyons Ubuntu is a GNU/Linux distro and is my distro of choice most of the time. I am typing this in Firefox running on Ubuntu 13.04 Raring beta running as the only OS on my Laptop. I am not against Ubuntu but do believe that the Ubuntu community would be stronger if it interacts more, not less, with the greater UNIX/GNU/Linux community. Witness the strength of the Stackoverflow community which gains strength rather than weakness from it's diversity. Stackoverflow has not splintered into C, Fortran and Visual C++ sub-fora but is richer for it's diversity.

Comment: Before that Please answer my question , If ubuntu is just another Gnu/linux why askubuntu have more than double of unix SE which allow all other distros and Unix ? :)

Comment: This has been discussed *many, many **MANY*** times and nothing is going to change. Please don't start a comment argument, otherwise the mods will have to intercede.

Comment: "You've been voted off the island"